# Check database schemas mysql

Tags: mysql

Is there a command in the MySQL command line client for windows that allows you to view all tables in a database, or display the schema of a particular table, similar to `.tables` in sqlite3 or `\dt` in psql?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[misread]

You're looking for `SHOW TABLES` it sounds like.

To see the schema of a table, use `DESCRIBE table_name;`

Comment: you can find more information querying the information schema. Take a look at select * from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'your_table' and table_schema = 'your_db'. Regards ;)

Comment: or, in more legible detailed form, `SHOW CREATE TABLE foo`

Answer (score 7):

```
show tables;
```

or

```
select table_name from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'your_db'
```

Answer (score 5):

As the other said for the table list - if you want to see schema of a particular table use

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE foobar;
```